# How could one defeat a pervasive antimagic field?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, magic, antimagic-field

There is a campaign I'm in that, though I'm pretty much done and ready to bail on it, has inspired a thought experiment.

Long story short, we got railroaded hard into being gladiators. We have had all of our gear stripped away and are stuck in a constant antimagic field (so even the synthesist summoner, me, is screwed since the DM said so).

So though I'm kinda done with the campaign already, as a thought exercise I am curious as to how I could beat that antimagic field that's constant throughout the entire place. Are there any good methods out there besides "Try to escape," or use the plot devices the DM gave us to use magic in the field, given that we lost all of our gear? Also, are there any summoner abilities I'm forgetting that may help?

Comment: Interestingly enough, I can't see why the Fused Eidolon wouldn't work (apart from GM fiat). It's neither (Sp) nor (Su), nor is it a summoned creature (it's not a creature), a magic item or a spell. In particular, the ability does not state "Eidolons are treated as summoned creatures" like the regular Eidolon does.

Comment: Sometimes my whole life feels like a pervasive antimagic field.

Answer (score 1):

**Nothing beats DM fiat - so this is probably just a thought exercise.** The real solution is to talk to your DM about this issue.

[Anti-Magic](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/antimagicField.html)
The rules suggest that if you had SR, you might be able to resist the effects of the anti-magic field. This would require a persuasive conversation with a DM though, as RAW only comments on summoned creatures with SR.

The rules also state that artefacts and Deities are unaffected by the field. However acquiring an artefact or attracting the attention of a deity may be difficult, particularly without magic to contact said deities.

[Otherwise while technically only Ex abilities work in an anti magic field](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/special-abilities), this [discussion](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2luk4?Can-you-cast-within-an-antimagic-field) might be of interest.

RAW Anti-magic is an [Emanation](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Aiming-a-Spell) this means it doesn't effect anything with cover from it's point or points of origin. So find somewhere to shut yourself away from (perhaps a cupboard? - you haven't given us any plot reason for the anti-magic field) it and then teleport to another plane, cast Wish to return magic to the area, summon creatures with SR (to use inside the anti-magic fields) or similar.

It seems likely the GM isn't using a strictly RAW variety of Anti-magic though.

Answer (score 0):

While there're many ways to lessen or to completly counteract anti-magic field's effects most of them recquire preparation. In this case you can try:
a. mage's disjunction to disspell the field.
b. use only divine intervention. Divine intervention is the only spell that directly states it's done by a God.
c. Try breaking the caster's concentration.
d. epic magic.
There're also some discussion points:
a. elven high magic states specifacally that it's only affected by wish, limited wish and disspell magic, but anti-magic field states that it effects everything except deities and artefacts.
b. is divine magic yours or your deitie's and how does it apply to warlocks
c. Wall of force and other on the wall of force based spells have the same problem as elven high magic.